# 2 bootstrap button in 1 line on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

how to make two buttons in one line using the bootstrap in the mobile display ? i use this code, but in the mobile view it displays 2 line.

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-centered">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a><br/>
                <h3>Ajukan Izin</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a><br/>
                <h3>Ajukan Cuti</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add to your button divs the classes: `col-xs-3` aswell to adjust it on mobile. On tablet views its `col-sm-3`

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18709/)

For a full reference to breakpoints in bootstrap check:
[Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the class col-sm-* in order to target small devices

Edit:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-centered">
        <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a><br/>
            <h3>Ajukan Izin</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a><br/>
            <h3>Ajukan Cuti</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would you like to share your code? i have changed it to sm but, it still same.

Comment: it still not worked. but thanks for your participation :)

Answer (score 0):

I edited wlalele's answer a little. The changes required here is adding extra class(`col-xs-3`) for smaller mobile device screens.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-centered">
        <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm col-xs-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-3 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a><br/>
            <h3>Ajukan Izin</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-3 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a><br/>
            <h3>Ajukan Cuti</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm col-xs-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```